# Does the AKKA FSM support Java 7?

Tags: lambda, java-8, akka, java-7, akka-fsm

I am learning the FSM framework provided by AKKA using its JAVA API, so far I've come across examples using Lambda expressions that are supported with Java8 onwards. Is Java 8 a requirement? Can I use FSM with Java 7?
If yes, are there any examples I can refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/java8-compat.html):

> Akka requires that you have Java 8 or later installed on your machine.

You cannot use Akka's FSM API, or any of the APIs in the current version of Akka, with Java 7. The last version of Akka that supported Java 7 was Akka 2.3, which [reached its end of life in April 2017](https://akka.io/docs/other-releases.html). Even in Akka 2.3, the Java variant of the FSM API used lambdas, which I think required the use of Java 8.

Comment: Blowing my mind with this 'documentation' concept. I hope it catches on!!

Comment: It says improvements with the Java 8 API in most places, so yeah, I hope it really gets better